# Sram T3 cracks when pedaling, but it works, in all three gears.The bike is three years in use

Tags: hub

My rear hub SRAM T3 cracks when pedaling, but it works, in all three gears.The bike is three years in use.What shoud be done, and how urgent is the problem?
I think it's something with the rear hub because the cracking sound is slightly different after each shifting of the gears.

Comment: Are you sure the cracking is coming from the rear hub? Since bicycles are made of hollow metal tubes, they're excellent at transporting sounds from different parts of the bike to entirely different parts of the bike.

Comment: Check out this [Sheldon Brown link](http://sheldonbrown.com/sachs-internal.html).

Comment: Are we talking about a creak (a noise) or a crack (a really loud noise like thunder)?  A crack is major cause for concern.  A creak could indicate a need for lubrication...

Comment: I see - it is a creak really. So I should have the hub lubricated first. Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

A crackling sound could be a bad bearing in the hub. Does it also feel gravelly (as if you have dirt in the hub) or do you hear a grinding sound as well?

Note that a single crack when changing gears is relatively normal. If all fails, go to your local bike shop to get a real opinion (internet opinions don't count).